# Determine if Android .APK has been pushed live in the Play Store Developer Console (or elsewhere)?

Tags: android

Is there a more definitive way to determine if an .APK I've uploaded is live or not, either via the Developer Console or elsewhere?

I always get the message this this could take several hours, etc.  I'm just curious if there is a way to tell if a particular .APK has passed the verifying/posting stage and begun rolling out to users devices?  Better yet, number of devices updated so far, stats like that?

Answer (score 0):

The Developer Console has all of those statistics and more.  From your Console, click your app, then select "Statistics" from the menu on the left.  It should be at the very top.  Once there, you'll find options to sort the data, including by App Version.  That will show you how many apps have upgraded, and how many haven't!

Comment: Thanks Tim.  I guess I overlooked this and it is indeed helpful, although it looks like these statistics are only updated daily.  I guess what I was/am more interested in is functionality more like TestFlight.com (testflightapp.com) where you can upload an alpha or beta, alert the group instantly via email that a new version is available and have the alpha/beta groups install and test more immediately.  I guess I should have mentioned in the question that this is more specifically an issue related to Play Store Developer Console Alpha/Beta groups.